# Do EnderStorage Ender Chests prevent strangers from accessing them if they make a chest with the same color code by accident?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

*Please note that this is a question about the minecraft mod EnderStorage, **NOT** vanilla ender chests.*

[image]

The EnderStorage mod has custom ender chests which can be privatised by using different dyes on the 3 color slots.

When it comes to using those on a server, what happens if someone accidentally makes an ender chest with the same color code as the one I'm using? Will that person be able to see the contents of my ender chest, or is there something in place to prevent that?

Comment: One of the main features of the chests in that mod is that they can also be accessed by machines (e.g. hoppers or pipes from other mods). That can only work if they're global, for everyone and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all EnderStorage chests with the same color code will connect to each other, regardless of who placed those chests. However, you can make an EnderStorage chest private by right clicking on the latch with a diamond. This will cause the chest to also be associated with you, and will now only connect that chest to other diamond-latched chests with the same color code.